# Undo accidentally minimized desktop (now all desktop icons gone)

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, mate-desktop, bugs

If you have a window active and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>N</kbd>, that window will be minimized.

It has happened to me a number of times that I did this while the topmost window was in fact *in*active (meaning the desktop had focus) -- in those instances, it was the desktop that got minimized, thus hiding all my desktop icons (on all my workspaces).

This must be a bug, or at least a misfeature, of **Linux Mint MATE v17.0, 64-bit edition** (and possibly others).

How do I unminimize the desktop, other than logging out and in again?

Comment: *Dear future reader:* I was just awarded the "Tumbleweed" for this post. If you should have an answer, you may safely assume that *I still desire your reply.*

Comment: Disregard the above comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and solved it by going into the `System Settings` -> `Desktop` -> uncheck/check the option `Show desktop icons`

That's a weird feature being able to minimize the desktop! Hopefully it'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the display manager either from terminal or by switching to a different TTY, e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>; and then execute:

```
# /etc/init.d/mdm restart
```

For more info and examples/ideas take a look at [this Linux Mint forum thread](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/801) as well as [this post on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143838/how-do-i-restart-cinnamon-from-the-tty).

Comment: This simple kill the desktop without start it in my case, not working ...